# Declarar Css para vários identificadores

Tags: css, css3

tenho algumas divs onde seus Css são iguais, porém seus identificadores são diversos devido ao Jquery.

Preciso simplificar o CSS que se repetem. É possível?

Veja que são todos iguais.

```css
<style>
         #owl-demo .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo2  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo3  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo4  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo5  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo6  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo7  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo8  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #owl-demo9  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }
  #div1 {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip; 
  }
      </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende da situação:

**1)** Se existirem itens com a classe `.item` e que você deseje aplicar uma formatação diferente, pode separar com vírgula.

Veja seu exemplo otimizado:

```
<style>
         #owl-demo .item, #owl-demo2  .item, #owl-demo3  .item
         , #owl-demo4  .item, #owl-demo5  .item, #owl-demo6  .item
         , #owl-demo7  .item, #owl-demo8  .item, #owl-demo9  .item{
         background: #42bdc2;
         padding: 3px 0px;
         margin: 5px;
         color: #FFF;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         border-radius: 3px;
         text-align: center;
         }

        #div1 {
        white-space: nowrap; 
        width: 100%; 
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: clip; 
        }
</style>
```

**2)** Se todos os elementos com a classe `.item` forem sofrer a mesma formatação, deve utilizar o indicado por Neuber Oliveira.

Leia mais sobre: [**SELETORES CSS**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que estude um pouco de CSS.

```
.item {
  background: #42bdc2;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Todos os elementos no seu html que tiverem a classe `item` vão ter o mesmo estilo. Sem saber a estrutura exata fica complicado exemplificar melhor.

Se só isso não resolver posta o HTML também.

Answer (score 2):

Se não tiveres a utilizar a class `.item` em mais lugar nenhum, o recomendado seria apontar os estilos diretamente para a class `.item`. No entanto se estiveres a utilizá-la em múltiplos lugares, o "*hack*" mais simples seria adicionar uma *class* ou um *id* com um nome aleatório como elemento "*parent*", e inserir todo esse conteúdo dentro desse elemento.

Por outras palavras:

```css
#container .item {
  background: #42bdc2;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
// continua ...
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- ### Novo ID adicionado como elemento parent ### -->
  <div id="owl-demo">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="owl-demo2">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- continua ... -->
</div>
```

Ou seja, todos os `.item` que se encontram dentro do *id* `#container`, este estilo acima será aplicado às mesmas.